# continue into something/continue something

Tags: sentence-construction

Is **continue into some activity** a correct construction?

> [By placing the two confidants in critical Ministries, Mr. Modi appears to loosen the grip of his own office on the government; the effects will be felt by National Security Adviser Ajit Doval if he ***continues into*** a second term, as is widely expected.](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/his-new-council/article27394436.ece)

I think **continue something** must be used here.

> If he continues a second term.

Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, one should use "continue into" in this construction, not jsut "continue" Thsi is because here "term" is a period of time. so one would write:

> - ... continue into a second year ...
> - ... continue into a fourth week
> - ... continue into her third semester
> - ... continue into his fifth month

Where the thing being continued is not a period of time, but is a condition or process, the "into" form is not used, as in:

> - The effects would be felt by Governor Jones if he continues his policy of ...
> - The issue will remain active if she continues to assert her right to ...

However, where the thing being continued is progress through separate units, "into" would be used:

> - The pace picked up and the racers continued into their second mile ...
> - The ordeal continued into its third day, as ...
> - The play continues into the third act, where the character Jack learns that ...
> - The project will continue into its third phase, with the installation of gizmos.
> - The story continues into the third chapter, where the reder first meets the character of Bess.

All of these are handled in the same way as the case of a period of time.